# React native webview: can't open blob url

Tags: react-native, blob, react-native-webview

In my React Native webview I open a page where there is a download button for a pdf. The pdf is downloaded through a blob url (blob:https://-------------/a2cb9bd4-4a7b-4e26-825d-024cdbb73d3c). When I tap this button nothing happens and I get no error. When I set the
setSupportMultipleWindows={false} property of the webview and tap the button it asks if i want to leave the page and if i tap yes, i get an error saying Can't open url: blob:https://----------/a2cb9bd4-4a7b-4e26-825d-024cdbb73d3c.

Any ideas how to get the pdf opened/downloaded from the blob url?

I tried fetching the url with fetch() to get the blob data but the network request fails.